# Adding custom views in android while knowing apps dimensions

Tags: java, android, layout, view

I've done a little bit of iOS programming but I am new to android. In iOS it is very easy to programmatically add views and I'm finding it's not so easy on android.

I want to add custom views to my app at certain points. I can create an array for these points but in order to do that I need to know the dimensions of my app. Once I create the array of points I want to add custom views at each point. Where do I do this? I can't do this inside onCreate() because it isn't possible to get dimensions. Is there a class I should extend and put this into?

Thanks!

Comment: Custom views are more easy in android to do, U can use "addOnGlobalLayoutListener" in onCreate to get the dimensions but you should use it in proper way.

Answer (score 0):

You can get dimensions in pixel by this code:

```
Point size;
Display display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
size = new Point();

display.getSize(size);//Gets the size of the display, in pixels.
display.getRealSize(size);//Gets the real size of the display without subtracting any window decor or applying any compatibility scale factors.

size.x;//width
size.y;//height
```

Run in onCreate() then you can create your views and add them.